# Can't Figure out why my submit button wont submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I can't figure out why my submit button wont submit right. I did have an e.preventDefault() at the top and it wouldn't do anything, but an instructor told me to put it in my conditions in the submit function and either it's a lazy answer or I'm just really confused because its still not working. It should refresh after all the correct inputs are in.

Heres my github file: https://github.com/joeEscob1023/interactiveForm/blob/master/js/app.js

Heres the code:

```
$("form").on("submit", e => {
  let nameInput = $(name).val();
  let emailInput = $(email).val();
  let cardNumber = $("#cc-num").val();
  let zipCode = $("#zip").val();
  let cvv = $("#cvv").val();

  //Will Refactor If statements
  if (!isValidName(nameInput)) {
    invalidSpans(" : Enter A Name", "name");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (!isValidEmail(emailInput)) {
    invalidSpans(" : Enter A Correct Email", "mail");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (!isValidActivity()) {
    invalidSpans(" : Enter Atleast One Activity", "activities");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (!isValidCreditCard(cardNumber)) {
    invalidSpans(" :Enter A Valid Credit Card Number", "cc-num");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (!isValidZipCode(zipCode)) {
    invalidSpans(" :Enter A Valid Zip Code", "zip");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!isValidCvv(cvv)) {
    invalidSpans(" :Enter A Valid CVV", "cvv");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

Comment: @Brilliand There are no validation errors shown to me.  I'd record a gif, but that isn't easily done on my workstation without expensive software.  However, I did get it to submit on the name(I used `Test Again` instead of `test`).

Comment: @Brilliand However, since the form submits fine, the OP is entering invalid data it seems.

Comment: This fiddle seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6rem9uL8/3/ - perhaps you're missing some validation errors?

Comment: Ill go through and look again. I just know the way I have it now, its just not doing anything. It wont refresh the page and it takes me to a 405 error for whatever reason. I'll check out the jsfiddle and keep testing.

Comment: Have you read about [error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)?

Comment: The page disappearing and showing you a 405 error proves that your submit button is working just fine.  The 405 error is a separate problem that isn't the fault of your JavaScript (it may be you have your form action set wrong, or your server misconfigured).

Answer (score 0):

your function seems correct may be validation issue